# Creating a function in C++ for best and worst grade

Tags: c++, function

I am new to programming and I must create a program that gives you information about the biggest and the smallest from the 3 numbers that you enter first. It must display as a text like for example "The grade in 
mathematics is the best grade" and "The grade in physics is the worst grade". I must do this as a function though and not with everything inside int main (). How can I do this? I can already do it as a code in int main (), but seem to be unable to create a function with the same purpose. Any help is greatly appreciated. That's what I've done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <std::string>

std::string subjectentry() {
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please enter your subject name " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    return name;
}

float gradeentry() {
    float grade;
    std::cout << "Please enter your grade." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> grade;
    return grade;
}

float Calculateaveragegrade(float grade1, float grade2, float grade3) {
    float averagegrade((grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3);
    return averagegrade;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "This program compares 3 of your subject grades and " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calculates your average grade." << std::endl;
    std::string subjectname1;
    std::string subjectname2;
    std::string subjectname3;

    float grade1;
    float grade2;
    float grade3;

    subjectname1 = subjectentry();
    subjectname2 = subjectentry();
    subjectname3 = subjectentry();

    grade1 = gradeentry();
    grade2 = gradeentry();
    grade3 = gradeentry();
    float result = Calculateaveragegrade(grade1, grade2, grade3);
    std::cout << "Your average grade is " << result << "." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is example code base on your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

std::string subjectentry() {
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Please enter your subject name " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> name;
    return name;
}

float gradeentry() {
    float grade;
    std::cout << "Please enter your grade." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> grade;
    return grade;
}

float CalculateAverageGrade(float grade1, float grade2, float grade3)
{
    float averagegrade((grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3);
    return averagegrade;
}

void getSobject(std::vector<std::string> & subject)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        subject.push_back(subjectentry());
    }

}


void getGrades(std::vector<float>& grades)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        grades.push_back(gradeentry());
    }

}


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> subject;
    std::vector<float> grades;
    std::cout << "This program compares 3 of your subject grades and " << std::endl;
    std::cout << "calculates your average grade." << std::endl;
    getSobject(subject);
    getGrades(grades);
    float result = CalculateAverageGrade(grades[0], grades[1], grades[2]);
    std::cout << "Your average grade is " << result << "." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```